# MySQL 5.5.37 Events Not Running and Everyting is Set

Tags: mysql

Sorry my English is bad, I use https://translate.google.com/ to write in English

My MySQL events never want to execute.
I use `MySQL 5.5.37`

Fisrt, I have

```
set Global event_scheduler=ON
```

with query `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

[image: output of show processlist]

sorry., my reputation is bad..

Next I have a recurring event on the master server.
This never want to execute. I also tried to change the date to different time.

```
CREATE EVENT `event_removemq` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS '2014-05-05 06:00:00' 
DO 
DELETE FROM mqraw$$
```

No error on this query, everything is good...

My question is, why events still will not be executed.? Please Help me...
thanks...

Comment: First make sure your server knows the right time with `SELECT NOW();`, then see if the event has been properly set up with `SHOW EVENTS;`. Maybe 6:00 was already over at the time you added the event?

Comment: thank you very much guys... but I was able to fix the problem...
In MySQL 5.5.37,, the default timezone is UTC... in my place use GMT +08:00...
so, I Change the timezone in MySQL with this Code

    SET time_zone = "Asia/Makassar"

And it's works... thanks a lot for the Answers..

Answer (score 0):

`Time` field of the `processlist` tells seconds elapsed since last execution of an active event.

As per your posting your event scheduler is up an running.

And to check if your specific event is up or not, you better execute following query

```
select * from information_schema.events where event_name='event_removemq'\G
```

With this you can know if the event is fired at least once or not.
Look into the field values of `LAST_ALTERED` and `LAST_EXECUTED`.

A typical output would show:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.events where EVENT_NAME = 'event_executed_at'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       EVENT_CATALOG: def
        EVENT_SCHEMA: so
          EVENT_NAME: event_executed_at
             DEFINER: root@localhost
           TIME_ZONE: SYSTEM
          EVENT_BODY: SQL
    EVENT_DEFINITION: DELETE FROM TMP_TABLE WHERE USER=user();
          EVENT_TYPE: RECURRING
          EXECUTE_AT: NULL
      INTERVAL_VALUE: 1
      INTERVAL_FIELD: MINUTE
            SQL_MODE: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
              STARTS: 2014-05-05 11:42:57
                ENDS: NULL
              STATUS: ENABLED
       ON_COMPLETION: NOT PRESERVE
             CREATED: 2014-05-05 11:48:57
        LAST_ALTERED: 2014-05-05 11:48:57
       LAST_EXECUTED: 2014-05-05 11:56:57
       EVENT_COMMENT:
          ORIGINATOR: 0
CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT: utf8
COLLATION_CONNECTION: utf8_general_ci
  DATABASE_COLLATION: utf8_general_ci
```